# 'ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I keep having the following error:

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

I am not able to insert into my database as well.

[image]

```cs
private void btnXoa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(chuoiKetnoi);
    if (MessageBox.Show("Bạn có chắc chắn muốn xóa ?", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Thuc hien xoa du lieu
        string delete = "delete from tblKET_QUA where MaSV='" + txtMaSinhVien.Text + "' and MaMH='" + cbbMonHoc.Text + "' ";
        using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delete, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Xóa dữ liệu thành công", "Thông báo!");

        // Trả tài nguyên
        cmd.Dispose();
        //Load lai du lieu
        load();
    }
}
```

Comment: please do not post image. Post your code as formatted text

Comment: Read the error message carefully.  It tells you precisely what is wrong.  That is also the wrong way to compose SQL queries

Comment: Missing `conn.Open();`

Comment: What happens if txtMaSinhVien.text contains the text "' or 1=1;--"

Answer (score 5):

The error message is clear to mention what you need to do. Your SQL connection is not open. You need to open it before executing the query.

```cs
conn.Open();
```

Reference: [SqlConnection.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

---

**Recommendation(s)**

1. Use Parameterized Query instead of concatenating value into query. This aimed to prevent SQL injection (Example: [Bobby-tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)) which is highly discussed in the StackOverflow community.
2. Apply `using` declaration/block for `SqlConnection conn` for disposing the connection automatically when it ends.
3. Remove `cmd.Dispose()` as you apply `using` declaration/block for `SqlCommand cmd`. The disposal will be automatically handled by `using`.

```cs
using SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(chuoiKetnoi);
if (MessageBox.Show("Bạn có chắc chắn muốn xóa ?", "Thông báo", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    conn.Open();

    // Thuc hien xoa du lieu
    string delete = "delete from tblKET_QUA where MaSV = @MaSV and MaMH= @MaMH";
    using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(delete, conn);
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaSV", /* SqlDbType */).Value = txtMaSinhVien.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaMH", /* SqlDbType */).Value = cbbMonHoc.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Xóa dữ liệu thành công", "Thông báo!");

    //Load lai du lieu
    load();
}
```

Comment: Good. You can also add "Don't block with a MessageBox while the connection is open"